# libgdx purpose of viewport with camera

Tags: java, libgdx

I often see in tutorials that people create a camera and pass that to the viewport, like so `viewport = new FillViewport(100,100,camera);`. Why isn't just creating a viewport not enough? Doesn't it automatically create a camera?

Thanks

Comment: It's also possible to just use a camera without a viewport. That's in my opinion the easiest way in lots of cases

Comment: @Number_987 But how will the game display properly across different screens without a viewport?

Comment: The camera already has it's own viewport settings. In lots of cases this is enough and you don't need an extra viewport. Example: Game world height is 10m. Next you set the camera.viewportHeight to 10. Than you set the camera.viewportWidth to 10 * screenWidth/screenHeight. Solved!

Comment: No problem ;) hope you  can use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't need to separately instantiate a camera. Most tutorials I've seen do not exclusively follow best practices, so keep that in mind when you read them. But in this case, it's just preference. You will probably want to get a reference to the viewport's camera regardless, so you can manipulate its position.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a camera can let you move in around, which most examples let you do.

Comment: You can move the viewport's camera whether or not you provided it at instantiation.